# Alternative for numpy.choose that allows an arbitrary or at least more than 32 arguments?

Tags: python, numpy

With my code I'm running into an issue where the `numpy.choose` methods does not accept all the arguments since it is limited by `NPY_MAXARGS` (`=32`). Is there an alternative available, that allows an arbitrary number of argument arrays or at least more than `32` that is as fast as `numpy.choose`?

```
choices = [np.arange(0,100)]*100
selection = [0] * 100
np.choose(selection, choices)

>> ValueError: Need between 2 and (32) array objects (inclusive).
```

Any help would be appreciated... :)

Comment: Give a realistic reason for using `choose`.  Your example just shows that there's limit in the number of choices.  What special features are you using?  Note the `abuse` warning in its docs.

Answer (score 7):

The indices can be given as lists. Assuming that `selections` has the same length as `choices`:

```
b = numpy.array(choices)
result = b[range(len(selections)), selections]
```

will give the value in choices specified by the index in selections. See it in action:

```
numpy.random.seed(1)
b = numpy.random.randint(0,100,(5,10))
>>> array([[37, 12, 72,  9, 75,  5, 79, 64, 16,  1],
          [76, 71,  6, 25, 50, 20, 18, 84, 11, 28],
          [29, 14, 50, 68, 87, 87, 94, 96, 86, 13],
          [ 9,  7, 63, 61, 22, 57,  1,  0, 60, 81],
          [ 8, 88, 13, 47, 72, 30, 71,  3, 70, 21]])

selections = numpy.random.randint(0,10,5)
>>> array([1, 9, 3, 4, 8])

result = b[range(len(selections)),selections]
>>>> array([12, 28, 68, 22, 70])
```

Comment: That's the only context where I recall `choose` being given as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 2):

`choose` has the 32 object limit because it broadcasts the arrays together.  Consider the error messages for these two actions:

```
In [982]: np.arange(33).choose(np.ones((33,33)))
...
ValueError: Need at least 1 and at most 32 array objects.
In [983]: np.broadcast(*range(33))
...
ValueError: Need at least 1 and at most 32 array objects.
```

An example exploiting that broadcasting, picking values from a 2d array, 1d and scalar.

```
In [998]: np.diag([2,1,0]).choose((np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), 0,[.1,.2,.3]))
Out[998]: 
array([[ 0.1,  1. ,  2. ],
       [ 3. ,  0. ,  5. ],
       [ 6. ,  7. ,  8. ]])
```

As `@Benjamin` shows `np.choose` can be used to select items from the successive columns of a 2d array - provided there aren't more than 32 columns

```
In [1002]: M=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [1003]: np.array([2,0,1]).choose(M)
Out[1003]: array([6, 1, 5])
In [1004]: M[[2,0,1],[0,1,2]]
Out[1004]: array([6, 1, 5])
```

It was in just such a context that I recall first seeing this 32 array limit to `choose`, and one of the few where I've seen `choose` used in an answer.

It is a compiled function, `PyArray_Choose` and `array_choose`

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0b2e590ec18942f8f149ab2306b80da86b04eaeb/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/945c308e96fb815729e8f8aeb0ad6b39b8bdf84a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c

I don't see any uses of this function in other compiled numpy code. And apart from testing, little use in rest of `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 6 years old, but since this is the first result on Google for the `Need at least 0 and at most 32 array objects` error, I thought I'd add this.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can probably just use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) (using an array to index another array):

```py
choices = np.array([np.random.random(5) for _ in range(5)])
keys = np.random.randint(choices.shape[0]-1, size = 10)

choices[keys]
```