# Python np.nditer() - ValueError: Too many operands

Tags: python, numpy

I have a few methods which pass different amount of messy data to this function to combine headers with data and return a list of dictionaries:

```
def zip_data(self, indicator_names, indicator_values):
    values = [[float(elem) for elem in item] for item in np.nditer(indicator_values)]
    return [dict(zip(indicator_names, row)) for row in values]
```

It's basically something like (they do the same):

```
def zip_large_data(self, indicator_names, indicator_values):
    data = []
    for item in np.nditer(indicator_values):
        values = []
        values.append(int(item[0]))
        for elem in item[1:]:
            values.append(float(elem))
        data.append(dict(zip(indicator_names, values)))
    return data
```

The thing is, it works great if a list of 20 elements is passed, but for like 40 it gives the error:

> File "xy.py", line 205, in momentum_indicators
>       return self.zip_large_data(momentum_indicator_names, momentum_indicator_values)
>
> File "xy.py", line 51, in zip_large_data
>       for item in np.nditer(indicator_values):
>
> ValueError: Too many operands

How many values can np.nditer() iterate over? Is there any way to avoid this?

## Edit

Small example:

> indicator_values = [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([5, 10, 15, 20,
>   25])]
>
> indicator_names = ['a', 'b']

Wanted output:

> data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 5}, {'a': 2, 'b': 10}, {'a': 3, 'b': 15}, {'a':
>   4, 'b': 20}, {'a': 5, 'b': 25}]

Current status:

```
def zip_large_data(self, indicator_names, indicator_values):
    data = []
    print(indicator_values[0])
    for item in np.nditer(indicator_values):
        print(item)
        values = []
        values.append(int(item[0]))
        for elem in item[1:]:
            values.append(float(elem))
        data.append(dict(zip(indicator_names, values)))
        print(data)
        break
    return data
```

Output:

> In: print(indicator_values[0])
>
> Out: [1 2 3 4 5]
>
> In: print(item)
>
> Out:(array(1), array(5))
>
> In: print(data)
>
> Out: [{'a': 1, 'b': 5}]

So basically I do not want to iterate through the indicator_values sequentially, but first elements of every array, then the second elements of every array etc.. I want to avoid nditer, but don't see how

Sorry English is not my first language, first time working with numpy, it's confusing.

Comment: Why are you using `nditer`?  Tell us about indicator_values. dtype? shape?

Comment: Using nditer because of numpy array, is there any other way to iterate through it?
indicator_values are a list of numpy arrays..
indicator_names are a list of predefined headers which are appointed to every element of the numpy arrays..

Comment: nditer is a specialized tool more useful in numpy C-api than python. You can iterate on the first dimension of a array directly.

Comment: Full docs for nditer -  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Comment: You need to provide a small working example.  I suspect the way you are using nditer is unusual and unintended.

Comment: Added small example, sorry wasn't here to post it earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting the `NPY_MAXARGS` limit.

I haven't seen a use like this for `nditer`, so it took me a bit to figure out what was happening.  And then I had use a python session to test my ideas.  A worked example would have helped.

Usually posters use `nditer` as a way of simply iterating through an array and do some calculation. Simple iteration (without `nditer) is usually faster.`nditer`is mainly a stepping stone toward implementing the idea in`cython`.

With a list of arrays, `nditer` broadcasts them together, and then iterates through the matching elements.  It's akin to the common Python list zip idiom (as implied by your function name).

```
In [152]: list(zip('abc',[1,2,3]))
Out[152]: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
In [153]: {k:v for k,v in zip('abc',[1,2,3])}
Out[153]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Defining 3 small arrays that can be broadcast against each other:

```
In [136]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [137]: b = np.array([[4],[5]])
In [138]: c = np.array([10])
In [140]: np.broadcast_arrays(a,b,c)
Out[140]: 
[array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), array([[4, 4],
        [5, 5]]), array([[10, 10],
        [10, 10]])]
```

With `nditer`:

```
In [143]: for x in np.nditer([a,b,c]):
     ...:     print(x)
     ...:     
(array(1), array(4), array(10))
(array(2), array(4), array(10))
(array(3), array(5), array(10))
(array(4), array(5), array(10))
```

and with your function:

```
In [155]: zip_large_data('abc',[a,b,c])
Out[155]: 
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4.0, 'c': 10.0},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 4.0, 'c': 10.0},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 5.0, 'c': 10.0},
 {'a': 4, 'b': 5.0, 'c': 10.0}]
```

If I do same sort of iteration with 32 operands if runs ok, but fails with 33

```
In [160]: for x in np.nditer([a,b,c]*11):
     ...:     pass 

ValueError: Too many operands
```

`numpy` has a 32 operand limit (and 32 dimension limit).  It isn't well documented, and doesn't come up often.  I've only seen it in questions using `np.choose`.

[Alternative for numpy.choose that allows an arbitrary or at least more than 32 arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162235/alternative-for-numpy-choose-that-allows-an-arbitrary-or-at-least-more-than-32-a)

[Using numpy.array with large number of dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192518/using-numpy-array-with-large-number-of-dimensions)

Comment: Thank you for the notice that it supports only 32 operands, still need to find a way to iterate over more :I

Comment: Do you need the broadcasting?  or are the arrays always 1d (and same length)?

Comment: Arrays are always 1d and same length yes

Comment: Does it work to replace the `nditer` with `zip(*indicator_values)`?

Comment: And thank you for your effort and patience, you just saved me.